# Why would single-use (harcoded) tokens not validate in the Message module, when the dynamic version does?

Tags: 7, message-subscribe

In the [Message](https://drupal.org/project/message) module, why does the following dynamic token validate nicely `[message:field-message-content:body]` but the single-use (harcdoded) token does not `@{message:field-message-content:body}`

Basically changing `[token]` to `@{token}` doesn't work.

Note: I know I have to create a new message and just can't change the template on the fly to back-propagate existing messages.

For reference from the module's readme.txt:

> ## Tokens
>
> - "Dynamic" tokens   When defining a message type, it is possible to use Drupal tokens in any of the   message fields, in order to inject
>     certain content into the field on the fly.   E.g. Entering the string
>     "[current-date:short]" to the message text will   display the current
>     request time instead of the token.   E.g. [message:user:mail] will be
>     replaced with the message author's username   (When displaying the
>     message).   If the message has fields (e.g field_node_ref), its
>     contents will accessible   by the token system as well under
>     [message:field_node_ref].   (For instance:
>     [message:field_node_ref:title]).   This relies on "Entity token"
>     module that ships with Entity API.   Enabling "Token" module is also
>     recommened, as it provides more tokens   and shows a token browser in
>     the message type creation page.
> - "Single use" tokens   The single-use tokens are similiar to the dynamic tokens, excepet they're   being replaced by their content as
>     the message is created; Meaning this   content will not get updated if
>     it's reference gets changed.   E.g. "@{message:user:name}" - Will be
>     replaced by the message author's name   (When creating the message).
>     You can use this for example when you know the user's name is not
>     going   to change, so there is no reason for re-checking all the time
>     the user   name -- hardcoding it makes more sense.

**Note**: There is nothing in the error logs. Essentially when I use the dynamic token, it works and if I change it to a hardcoded token, then it doesn't. Basically changing `[token]` to `@{token}` it no longer works. I know I have to create a new message and just can't change the template too.

Comment: can you provide any more information please?  any error message?  logs?

Comment: Nothing in the error logs. Essentially when I use the dynamic token, it works and if I change it to a hardcoded token, then it doesn't. Basically changing [token] to @{token} it no longer works. I know I have to create a new message and just can't change the template too.

Comment: @Alex, if you have any ideas, I have 21 hours left to award the bounty. If not it gets wasted. :(

Comment: oh boy, gold rush is on!

Comment: :) big. big money on the line. lol

Comment: sorry bud I just couldn't find time :(

Comment: oh well. Time to code my own stuff then.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you're using Rules to send the message, i'll suggest you to manually save the message entity after having set all required fields but right before sending the message.

Single Use token are evaluated at save time.

Comment: The problem is not in rules. The actual message entity doesn't save the token. I have a body field and basically changing [node:body] to @{node:body} doesn't work.

Answer (score -3):

"Single use" tokens may saved to database one time and not be changed when update relate entity,while  "Dynamic" tokens was replace when theme the message.

Comment: My question was not, "What is the difference between the two?", but "Why does one validate and the other doesn't?"